# How can I stop EditText from being padded on the left?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

My `EditText` widgets seem to be padded on the left side and they don't align with the text above them. Is that normal? Is there a way to make it flush?

EDIT: Since it wasn't clear, I am talking about "Hello world" and "Title" not being aligned on the left. It is like "Title" has extra padding. The line under "Title" also has the same extra space on the left.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.hinttest.MainActivity"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="#000000">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="#000000">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: your whole layout has left padding `android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"`

Comment: I'm talking about the difference in padding between "Hello world" and "Title"

Comment: TextInputLayout has built in padding, you must compensate the Hello World TextView by adding paddingLeft to it. Or apply a negative marginLeft to the TextInputLayout to match the TextView

Comment: @ClintDeygoo I kind of figured that is what is going on, is there no way to remove that? is there a way to know the exact value of that padding?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the left padding that you are setting by removing this line: `android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"` from :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.hinttest.MainActivity"
    >
```

Comment: I'm talking about the difference in padding between "Hello world" and "Title"